# How to delete own answer

Tags: support

I remember seeing comments against answers advising users that they can delete their own posts (regardless of reason).

When I check my own answers, I do see a *delete* option; however, when I hover the mouse pointer over it, I see a message "vote to delete this post". I don't want to end up downvoting my own answer in a *failed* attempt to delete it.

A simple search did not help me, so the closest *formal* information I could find on SE that deleting own posts **is** allowed is in the "badges" section.

An example:
Peer Pressure - Delete own post with score of -3 or lower

So, it is possible for me to delete my own posts, right? Wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: The tooltip when you hover the mouse over it is misleading. If it is your own post, you don't vote: you just delete it (if you are allowed to: you can't delete an answer that was accepted by the owner the question). Delete votes aren't connected to downvotes so you wouldn't have to worry about that in any case.